# Variable not defined in while loop in python?

Tags: python, while-loop

I am trying to write a simple program in python to read command line arguments and print a final word based on the arguments. If there is any argument of the form "-f=" then the  will go to the front of the final printed word. Similarly for "-e=" the text goes to the back and if there is -caps as an argument then the final printed word will all be uppercase. I do a while loop to scan through the arguments and check for these flags. The full code is:

```
import sys 
i=1
while i<len(sys.argv):
    frnt_wrd = None
    lst_wrd = None 
    arg_1 = str(sys.argv[i])
    if arg_1.startswith('-f='):
        front = arg_1.split('=')
        frnt_wrd = front[1]

    elif arg_1.startswith('-e='):
        last = arg_1.split('=')
        lst_wrd = last[1]

    if arg_1.startswith('-caps'):
        caps = True

    else:
        word = arg_1
    i+=1
print (front)
print (frnt_wrd)
```

I had a couple of if statements later on to print out the word based on whether frnt_wrd and lst_wrd were not equal to None (i.e. a value had been assigned to them) but nothing was printing out. To check the problem I did:

```
print (front)
print (frnt_wrd)
```

and the output actually gives me front as the desired array (when there is an argument of the form "-f=" but returns frnt_wrd as None even though I defined:

```
frnt_wrd = front[1]
```

When I type exactly this line outside of the while loop it actually works but why is it not defining the frnt_wrd inside the while loop?

Edit: The full code giving me frnt_wrd as None is above. What else do you need?
I would like to learn how to do it with while and without argparse. I need to understand why I am defining a variable and it is not defining.

Traceback:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IqgAa.png)

Comment: Why are you not using [argparse](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html)? Also, can you please edit in the full traceback to your question?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation, as suggested when you created this account.  [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) applies here.  We cannot effectively help you until you post your MCVE code and accurately describe the problem.
We should be able to paste your posted code into a text file and reproduce the problem you described.

Comment: `i += 1` needs to be indented so it's part of the loop. Why don't you just use `for arg in sys.argv[1:]:`?

Comment: "Edit: The full code giving me frnt_wrd as None is above. What else do you need?" The full traceback, as I asked for. i.e. all of the lines that get spat out when you hit an error

Comment: Wow nice to know you guys are welcoming to new programmers.

Comment: I ask why is the variable not defined and you come spill out all the modules you know without addressing the question.

Comment: Thanks Barmar though, I appreciate it.

Comment: @MystMan "all the modules" is one module that I happen to think will make your life easier. I also just asked for a traceback. I also didn't downvote. It can feel a bit brutal joining SO and, if in doubt, read comments as being objective rather than intending to be condescending/hurtful/etc.

Comment: Ok I didnt know what traceback meant. I will look into argparse too. I appreciate the intention.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you reset `frnt_word` and `lst_word` to `None` each time through the loop, so you're overwriting the value that was set by a previous argument. You should just initialize them *before* the loop.

```
frnt_word = None
lst_word = None
caps = False
word = None
for arg in sys.argv[1:]:
    optarr = arg.split("=")
    if optarr[0] == "-f":
        frnt_word = optarr[1]
    elif optarr[0] == "-e":
        lst_word = optarr[1]
    elif optarr[0] == "-caps":
        caps = True
    else:
        word = arg
```