# how to refresh this api so it's get updated every 5 seconds

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

```
eth_api = "https://api.coinbase.com/v2/exchange-rates?currency=ETH"
headers = {"Accept": "application/json"}

r = requests.request("GET", eth_api, headers=headers)
data2 = r.json()
eth_price = data2['data']['rates']['USD']
print (eth_price)
```

I am still new to this, tried other ways but they are not effective, i want to reuse this in commands

Comment: You might want to use a while loop and the time.sleep(5) inside it.

Comment: And what do you mean by refreshing? Is it printing the price for every 5 seconds on the console?

Comment: @Underoos I want to update the price, check every 5 seconds and i have tried the loop thing with command it doesn't load the bot

i am trying to make a command to get the eth price but it stays same

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `while loop` and `time`. Here's an example for you

```
import time
import requests

eth_api = "https://api.coinbase.com/v2/exchange-rates?currency=ETH"
headers = {"Accept": "application/json"}

# initialize variable before the loop.
data2 = None

while True:
    r = requests.request("GET", eth_api, headers=headers)
    data2 = r.json()
    eth_price = data2['data']['rates']['USD']
    print (eth_price)

    # Wait 5 seconds before continuing.
    time.sleep(5)
```

Comment: Yeah I did exactly same but when i am using this in a command it gives me error that data2 is not defined

```
@client.command() 
async def eth(ctx):
    await ctx.message.delete()
    await ctx.send(f"The price of ETH is {eth_price}$")
```

Comment: I changed my answer according to  [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49417841/variable-not-defined-in-while-loop-in-python) topic.

Comment: NOTE: I tested what I posted, and it worked well for me.

Comment: can you help me more

It's printing the eth price but i think it's causing the bot to stop

I have a keep_alive() function at the end

from flask import Flask
from threading import Thread

app = Flask('')

@app.route('/')
def home():
    return "Hello. I am alive!"

def run():
  app.run(host='0.0.0.0',port=8080)

def keep_alive():
    t = Thread(target=run)
    t.start()

Comment: Did you try the edited answer?

Comment: also this at the end, it connects the bot to discord

client.run(os.getenv('TOKEN'))

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/241894/discussion-between-suleyman-celik-and-trayansh-agarwal).

Answer (score 0):

By updating do you mean to run this block of code every 5 seconds.
If you are trying to do that then you have to put the block of code in a while loop and put time.sleep(5) to run the loop every 5 seconds.
NOTE ~ You can't close the running process or the loop will stop so as your script.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).